# onload image, call function to display alert

Tags: angularjs, onload

My angular.js knowledge is very limited. Currently I have an image loading via

```
<img class="main" ng-src="{{URL}}{{magazine[pdf][page].url}}"/>
```

This works fine, so I won't bother with the js code. I wish to get an alert when the image has loaded. So I changed the code to

```
<img class="main" ng-src="{{URL}}{{magazine[pdf][page].url}}" onload="preLoad()"/>
```

angular.js

```
$scope.preload = function() {
    alert("Image is loaded");
};
```

When the image loads initially I get no alert. When I refresh the page and the image is loaded from cache, then I get an alert. What am I missing here?

Comment: Without seeing all of your code it's hard to determine the best way to do this.  But you could add an if statement in your controller: if($scope.magazine) { alert('Loaded'); }

Comment: I tried this but similar results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best implementation I stumbled across, but it seems to work;

I gave the HTML element an id

```
<img class="main" id="mainImage" ng-src="{{URL}}{{magazine[pdf][page].url}}"/>
```

And added this jScript at the end of my controller

```
    var imageLoaded = document.getElementById('mainImage');

    imageLoaded.onload = function () {
        alert ("Image has loaded!");        
    };
```

I'm not sure exactly why this works over my original implementation but im leaving this here for anyone else looking for a 'solution'